# Build the java project using build.xml in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build, netbeans-7

When I try to do **Clean and Build project** in Netbeans for the project [Jsignpdf](https://github.com/kwart/jsignpdf/) I get below error. But If I debug the project it runs without error as I have included all the required libraries. I have limited knowledge of java and it is the first project I am trying to build.

```
 ant -f "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\jsignpdf-master" clean jar
    clean:
    Cleaning build
    C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\jsignpdf-master\build.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\jsignpdf-itxt\src\build.xml:10: taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found
     using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

As seen in this error message i clicked on the first build.xml link and it was pointing out below portion(target name="clean")

```
<target name="clean">
        <echo message="Cleaning build" />
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${output.dir}"/>
        <ant antfile="../jsignpdf-itxt/src/build.xml" useNativeBasedir="true" target="clean" />
</target>
```

When i clicked on second build.xml link mentioned in error i got below portion of xml highlighted.

```
<taskdef name="jarbundler" classname="net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${jarbundler.jar}"/>
        </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Actually i was getting lot of errors and solved them. There was also error like JarBundler not found.then I downloaded it from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarbundler/).It had .java files,not class files. So I created a package as relevant like `net.sourceforge.jarbundler` and placed the files which required. After doing all these I am still getting errors while building as described above. I googled a lot for building java app, build xml, ants etc etc and not able to resolve the errors after from last two days. Now my only hope is to some one help me on this error.For more information please download the project.

Comment: Where have you put the `jarbundler` jar?

Comment: If you are using Netbeans why are you building manually?

Comment: @Octopus i created a package jarbundler and placed the .java files related to jarbundler. I think i am missing something there

Comment: @RomanC I don't know. What do u mean by manually? What is the proper method to build project in netbeans?

Comment: You need to provide the exact location or expression,which results to the location of the `jarbundler.jar`. This expression `location="${jarbundler.jar}` is completely wrong.

Comment: @Octopus Ok.I didn't change anything in build.xml after downloading the project. It would be better if you tell what should i do now, instead of mentioning that it is wrong.Please guide me on this.

Comment: @ITresearcher I don't work with Netbeans, but as far as I remember it uses internal framework for building a project, and creates a `build.xml` that you shouldn't modify by hands.

Comment: @RomanC May be. As i said before i downloaded the project from the website.It had build.xml. I just tried to build the project as it is.

Comment: As it is you can build only on the project creator's machine, but you can recreate a project before you try to build it.

Comment: Netbeans uses Ant by default. The project is just a simple Ant project. There's nothing special about it. There should be a `project.properties` file that defines variables `${}`. Look through this and check the paths. Add in another property for where you placed `jarbundler.jar` and link it in the `location`. What you currently have is wrong unless there is a property `jarbundler.jar` in `project.properties`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i have done as you mentioned now i get only this error "C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\jsignpdf-master\build.xml:10: taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Comment: @BoristheSpider In project.properties i have ${file.reference.jarbundler-2.2.0.jar} and file.reference.jarbundler-2.2.0.jar=lib-build/jarbundler-2.2.0.jar  I changed build.xml to <pathelement location="${jarbundler-2.2.0.jar}"/> But still not working

Comment: @BoristheSpider Please check my last comment. Still i am getting same error.

Comment: You have `file.reference.jarbundler-2.2.0.jar=lib-build/jarbundler-2.2.0.jar` so surely you need `${file.reference.jarbundler-2.2.0.jar}`? Try to understand what things mean rather than just hacking.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i have got jarbundler-2.2.0.jar file inside lib-build folder

Comment: @BoristheSpider i have installed eclipse and imported the project as jsignpdf was a eclipse project.It will recognize all the required libraries from lib folder(in netbeans i had to do some changes). But in eclipse when i run i get same error "D:\workspace\jsignpdf-itxt\src\build.xml:10: taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]"